# why is the if elseif failing?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xdebug

Sorry for posting this whole function. It is not my code and I am trying to get it to work. I am walking through the code with a debugger. The first if fails, as it should. But then instead of evaluating the next elseif (and the next elseif, etc), the function returns! Sorry if this is obvious. Shouldn't the debugger step through every elseif?

```
    protected function getState()
    {
        $rsegments_array = $this->ci->uri->rsegment_array();

        if(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && is_numeric($rsegments_array[3]))
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/upload_file/'.$rsegments_array[3]);
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/'.$rsegments_array[3].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url, 'relation_value' => $rsegments_array[3]);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[4] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;
           return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif( (empty($rsegments_array[3]) && empty($this->relation_field)) || (!empty($rsegments_array[3]) &&  $rsegments_array[3] == 'ajax_list'))
        {
            $upload_url = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/upload_file');
            $ajax_list_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ajax_list');
            $ordering_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/ordering');
            $insert_title_url  = site_url($rsegments_array[1].'/'.$rsegments_array[2].'/insert_title');

            $state = array( 'name' => 'list', 'upload_url' => $upload_url);
            $state['ajax'] = isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'ajax_list'  ? true : false;
            $state['ajax_list_url'] = $ajax_list_url;
            $state['ordering_url'] = $ordering_url;
            $state['insert_title_url'] = $insert_title_url;

            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'upload_file')
        {
            #region Just rename my file
            $new_file_name = '';
            //$old_file_name = $this->_to_greeklish($_GET['qqfile']);
            $old_file_name = $this->_convert_foreign_characters($_GET['qqfile']);
            $max = strlen($old_file_name);
            for($i=0; $i< $max;$i++)
            {
                $numMatches = preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.-_]+$/', $old_file_name[$i], $matches);
                if($numMatches >0)
                {
                    $new_file_name .= strtolower($old_file_name[$i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $new_file_name .= '-';
                }
            }
            $file_name = substr( substr( uniqid(), 9,13).'-'.$new_file_name , 0, 100) ;
            #endregion

            $results = array( 'name' => 'upload_file', 'file_name' => $file_name);
            if(isset($rsegments_array[4]) && is_numeric($rsegments_array[4]))
            {
                $results['relation_value'] = $rsegments_array[4];
            }
            return (object)$results;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && isset($rsegments_array[4]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'delete_file' && is_numeric($rsegments_array[4]))
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'delete_file', 'id' => $rsegments_array[4]);
            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'ordering')
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'ordering');
            return (object)$state;
        }
        elseif(isset($rsegments_array[3]) && $rsegments_array[3] == 'insert_title')
        {
            $state = array( 'name' => 'insert_title');
            return (object)$state;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like all of the elseifs have returns, so could it be that one of the conditions is met, but your debugger just isn't stopping at your breakpoints for some reason?  Maybe throw something like `error_log(__LINE__)` or `echo __LINE__` in every elseif, to be certain if any of them are firing.
It could also be that the data doesn't match any of the conditions..

Comment: *Shouldn't the debugger step through every elseif?* No, if it finds a elseif which is true it executes the code (and returns $whatever), to check if nothing is true, place a else clause at the end

Comment: You do not need any `elseif` there. Every `if` ends up with `return` statement ... so just replace `elseif` by just `if` and it will be easier to read & go through. Then try your debugging again. P.S. (somehow stupid, but just in case) make sure that you use "step over" or "step in" and not other debugger action.

Comment: Thanks. I took your recommendation and replaced the elseif with if. Now I can see that the case that I need is just not in the code. I don't know enough about this code to make it work. I found a competing product last night (phpGrid) and it supports Postgresql which is a real advantage. I am going to try to switch the image function of my code over to using that. thx.

Answer (score 0):

The code may not be working because of `elseif` itself. `elseif` is used for short hand if statements like `if(): elseif(): endif;` You may need to update all failing elseifs to `else if` with a space.